# jqGrid Multiple CheckBox in a column

Tags: jquery, jqgrid-php

I need help on below code.

```
var mydata = [
    {
    id: "1",
    invdate: "2010-05-24",
    name: "test",
    note: "note",
    tax: "10.00",
    total: "2111.00"},
    {
        id: "2",
        invdate: "2010-05-25",
        name: "test2",
        note: "note2",
        tax: "20.00",
        total: "320.00"},
    {
    id: "3",
    invdate: "2007-09-01",
    name: "test3",
    note: "note3",
    tax: "30.00",
    total: "430.00"},
    {
        id: "4",
        invdate: "2007-10-04",
        name: "test",
        note: "note",
        tax: "10.00",
        total: "210.00"},
    {
        id: "5",
        invdate: "2007-10-05",
        name: "test2",
        note: "note2",
        tax: "20.00",
        total: "320.00"}
    ];

jQuery("#list47").jqGrid({
    data: mydata,
    datatype: "local",
    height: 150,
    rowNum: 999999,
    scroll: true,
    colNames: ['Inv No', 'Date', 'Client', 'Amount', 'Tax', 'Total','Testing', 'Notes'],
    colModel: [
        {
        name: 'id',
        index: 'id',
        width: 60,
        sorttype: "int"},
    {
        name: 'invdate',
        index: 'invdate',
        width: 90,
        sorttype: "date",
        formatter: "date"},
    {
        name: 'name',
        index: 'name',
        width: 100},
    {
        name: 'amount',
        index: 'amount',
        width: 80,
        align: "right",
        sorttype: "float",
        formatter: "number"},
    {
        name: 'tax',
        index: 'tax',
        width: 80,
        align: "right",
        sorttype: "float"},
    {
        name: 'total',
        index: 'total',
        width: 80,
        align: "right",
        sorttype: "float"},
    { name: "Id_ListaMultiple", index:"Id_ListaMultiple",editable:true,edittype:"custom",editoptions:{custom_element:multiCheckElem, custom_value:multiCheckVal,list:let_val()}},
    {
        name: 'note',
        index: 'note',
        width: 150,
        sortable: false}
    ],
    pager: "#plist47",
    //viewrecords: true,
    //multiselect: true,
    caption: "single selection",
     gridComplete: function() {
        $("#list47_cb").css("width","100px");
        $("#list47 tbody tr").children().first("td").css("width","100px");
        }
});
jQuery("#list47").jqGrid('navGrid','#plist47',{edit:true,add:true,del:true,search:true});

    function multiCheckElem(values, optio) {
    var id = optio.id;
    alert(values);
    var ctl = '<div id="'+ id + '" class="checklist">';
    var ckboxAry = optio.list.split(';');
    var aValues = [];
    if (values && values.length)
    {
        aValues = values.split(",");
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < ckboxAry.length; i++)
    {
        var item = ckboxAry[i].split(':');
        ctl += '<input type="checkbox" ';

        if (aValues.indexOf(item[0]) != -1)
        {
            ctl += 'checked="checked" ';
        }
        ctl += 'value="' + item[0] + '"> ' + item[1] + '</input><br/>';
    }
    return ctl + '</div>';
}

function multiCheckVal(elem, action, val) {
    var items = '';
    if (action == 'get') // submitted
    {
        $("input[type=checkbox]:checked", elem).each(function (i, e)
        {
            if (items) items += ","
            items += e.value;
        });
    }
    else // launched
    {
    }
    return items;
}
function let_val(){
    return "2:Reposición;1:Solicitud Inicial;0:test";
}
```

Check this fiddle link too
http://jsfiddle.net/suddatshende/p3e7kukv/

I am trying to get the let_val function's return value to list under custom edittype and create multiple check box's, but i don't know how to do it, could not find any related answer, i have just started using jqGrid And my first Question ever on stack!
I solved the Issue, also edited the answer :)!